# SharePoint 2013 WorkFlows Stuck in suspended mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

SharePoint 2013 Workflows get stuck in suspended mode (http 404) and can only be stopped by terminating the workflow (error examples are attached). SharePoint 2010 workflows work fine.

Below are the errors i am getting

Resume this workflow

> RequestorId: 4df21985-3777-060b-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["20"],"SPRequestGuid":["4df21985-3777-060b-9515-2083fcdd326e"],"request-id":["4df21985-3777-060b-9515-2083fcdd326e"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4667"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Mon,
>   11 May 2015 13:31:49
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Activity in progress

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to
>   https://SiteName/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'1694c025-918c-4d91-9bc3-af1757a91248')
>   Correlation Id: de58ded0-1043-303b-be53-eb3dd43e732b Instance Id:
>   b7a8a87a-cd41-4806-9fb5-7f9a9a445e0d Retry now
>
> RequestorId: de58ded0-1043-303b-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400
>   {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   System.InvalidOperationException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Operation
>   is not valid due to the current state of the object."}}}
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["12"],"SPRequestGuid":["de58ded0-1043-303b-95e4-d3ddb9df0c7b"],"request-id":["de58ded0-1043-303b-95e4-d3ddb9df0c7b"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4667"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Mon,
>   11 May 2015 13:06:40
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Friday:

> RequestorId: f7eb131a-e809-d2f4-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400
>   {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   System.InvalidOperationException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Operation
>   is not valid due to the current state of the object."}}}
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["15"],"SPRequestGuid":["f7eb131a-e809-d2f4-b4ef-56b6ef13e501"],"request-id":["f7eb131a-e809-d2f4-b4ef-56b6ef13e501"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4667"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Fri,
>   08 May 2015 20:56:39
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: That, unfortunately, could be a lot of things. Can you use write to history actions to find out where the code is failing? Does it start and then stop when trying to do something specific (send an email, read a list, perform an action, exchange a token, etc)? Is this box/farm patched to SP1 or higher?

Comment: What i did fixed a part of  it but still having issues at the SubSite Level, i turned on the workflow app permission feature at that site collection level and bumped up the permission of the user and it works fine at the root site now the users at subsite are getting errors at the SubSite level

Comment: I am getting "Unable to properly communicate with the wokflow service" Error

Comment: Are workflows turned on on the subsite?

Comment: @Graham yes they are turned on  the Fix to the issue was it was ADFS that was causing all the trouble  and the user who was trying to initiate the workflow didnt have his email attribute configured correctly

Comment: Try to hit this URL. https://SiteName/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'1694c025-918c-4d91-9bc3-af1757a91248') In New browser window.

Comment: This URL is having GUID. First figure out which list is belongs to? And then check your workflow action which uses this list. Most of the time it is the issue workflow history list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the interesting part of your error message is this:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

It seems some people have found success by increasing the `MaxHttpCollection` value in the web.config file.

Sources: [here](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/DotNet/d/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-317.aspx) and [here](https://support.winshuttle.com/hc/en-us/articles/200296730-Error-Operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-)